# Python: ImportError - Reason: image not found

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.6

I am trying to do something as simple as:

```
import pymrmr
```

But I then get these warnings and errors:

> /Users/kimrants/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/**init**.py:36:
>   FutureWarning:
>
> Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to
>   `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as
>   `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        28 
>        29 # MRMR
>   ---> 30 import pymrmr
>        31 
>        32 #Plotly
>
> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Users/kimrants/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymrmr.cpython-36m-darwin.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libiomp/lib/libiomp5.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/kimrants/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymrmr.cpython-36m-darwin.so
>   Reason: image not found

Has anyone seen this before? I first tried to solve this via `brew install llvm`, but this did not solve it.

Thanks!